# PHP Blackjack aces algorithm

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP version of Blackjack. I'm having trouble dealing with the aces. I know this is a particular problem when it comes to coding this game. I've had a look around at some of the other questions that others have asked, but I can't find just what I'm looking for.

I think the problem lies in the fact that once the getValue function is called on for a particular card, it doesn't call on it again for that card. Is there a way to get it to call on the getValue function again if, for example, you hit with an ace and a 7 (which is 8 or 18) and you get a 10 (turning it to 18 or 28). With the game I've built it goes bust in that scenario because it doesn't check the cards again to get the total.

Code is below. I hope it makes sense out of context and I've explained the problem well enough.

```
function getValue($drawn, $total){
    $splitter = str_split($drawn);
    $value = $splitter[0];
    if($value == 'j' or $value == 'q' or $value == 'k' or $value == 1){
        $value = 10;
    }else if($value == 'a' and (($total + 11) > 21)){
        $value = 1;
    }else if($value == 'a' and (($total + 11) <= 21)){
        $value = 11;
    }else{
        $value = $value;
    }
    return $value;
}

function calculateScore($cardsArray){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cardsArray); ++$i){
        $total += getValue($cardsArray[$i]);
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: By any chance, are you consistently coding aces as `'a'`, or are they sometimes encoded as `1`?  The fourth line has `or $value == 1` which makes me suspect the latter.

Comment: For starters, you're calling getValue with 1 parameter, $total isnt defined in scope, do you mean "... $value == 'k' or $value == 1..." and you lost me at "$value = $value;"

Comment: That line is to deal with 10s which are stored as 10h, 10d, 10s, 10c. The str_split is only taking the first value of the string in the array so it would count it as a 1 if I didn't do that. :)

Oh and $value = $value is for counting 1-9 because they're stored as 1d, 2d, 3d etc so the str_split is taking the number as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need to "know" when you have two total value possibilities based on one common set of cards is a good reason to use OOP here.

You could have a `hand` class, to which you deal `card` s, and if your card is `ace` you know that it has two values.

Upon receipt of an ace you could either duplicate your hand and run both hands until end, or you could write your `hand` and `card` classes such that `$hand->getTotal()` returns an array with *all possible totals*.

This is trivially easy with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the final score of the final `cardsArray`, you could sort the array from high to low with `rsort()` so that the ace value is always counted last and therefore you don't need to reevaluate it later.